# Landsat in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, landsat

I need to learn how to download, import and compose Landsat 8 in ArcGIS for natural colors (preferably in a GeoTIFF format). I have tried on my own but it seems that I am doing something wrong...

Can anyone help me and tell me the exact steps please?

Comment: Try the Exercise 8: Creating a mosaic dataset to contain Landsat imagery to start with http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000023p000000 Landsat 8 does have different bands to Landsat 7 http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/24/band-combinations-for-landsat-8/

Comment: You can download Landsat-8 (and other data) for free from Glovis (http://glovis.usgs.gov/).

Comment: Thank you for your responses :) @Mapperz I tried your link but the instructions are for Landsat 7 and it gets so complicated, Landsat 8 has one more band(instead of 6 it has 7) so everything changes...

Answer (score 10):

I've only worked with Landsat 7 imagery but I believe the same technique apply for composing:

You need to create an RGB composite so use the **Composite Bands tool** (ArcToolbox -> Data Management Tools -> Raster -> Raster Processing -> Composite Bands)

**Add the three R G B bands in the RGB order:
Band 4 (Red)
Band 3 (Green)
Band 2 (Blue)**

If you don't add them in exactly this order the result will not yield a natural colour image.

You can also add ALL the bands and later re-order the bands to perform different type of analysis;  With Landsat 7 I add 6 bands in the following order 3,2,1,4,5,7 (3 being R=Red, 2 being G=Green, 1 being B=Blue) This combination will also yield a natural colour image but it will also contain the other bands so you can then switch the bands to show Near Infra Red, etc.

I see Landsat 8 has some extra bands but if you decide to add more then the 3 RGB bands you must exclude the Panchromatic band - you use that to sharpen the image after the bands have been composited. I would also leave out BQA since and possibly B1 unless you need it in your analysis. So the composite order you could try is B4, B3, B2, B5, B6, B7, B19, B11.  That should generate a natural colour image with most of the bands included.

Once created the image might appear washed out and too light but you can enhance the colour contrast in the Display properties of Layer Properties. (I increase Contrast 35% and lower Brightness to -25%)

The image will be 30m resolution but you can now pan-sharpen to 15m using the panchromatic band (B8)

To Pan-sharpen the image use the **"Create Pan-sharpened Raster Dataset"** tool (ArcToolbox -> Data Management Tools -> Raster -> Raster Processing -> Create Pan-sharpened Raster Dataset)

Pan-sharpenning should be straight forward - select the Input Raster, optionally the Infrared channel, Output Raster and Input Panchromatic image.  The result will be a natural colour image with higher resolution (15m).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With respect to a natural color image stack, not much has changed. **The short answer is that you can create an RGB natural color image from Landsat 8 Bands 4,3,2.** Here's a breakdown of Landsat 8's bands, from the Google Earth Engine team (personal communication):

- B1: A new band, useful for studying water and atmospheric aerosol
  concentrations
- B2: Blue
- B3: Green
- B4: Red
- B5: Near Infrared
- B6: Short wave infrared 1
- B7: Short wave infrared 2
- B8: Fifteen meter panchromatic band
- B9: A new band for detecting cirrus clouds
- B10: Thermal infrared 1
- B11: Thermal infrared 2
- BQA: A quality assessment band

For more information, consult:

- [Landsat 8 Homepage](http://landsat.usgs.gov/LDCM_Landsat8.php)
- [Detailed breakdown of bandwidths for each of the Landsat missions](http://landsat.usgs.gov/band_designations_landsat_satellites.php)
- [Comparison between Landsat 7 and Landsat 8 bands](http://landsat.usgs.gov/L8_band_combos.php)

Comment: This answer is out of topic - he has been asking on the process how to create RGB composite in ArcGIS software, not for a description of Landsat bands.