# Pan-sharpening Landsat 8 All bands using Arcgis 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, landsat, pansharpening

I need to pan-sharpen a landsat 8 image with at least 5 bands using Arcgis 10.3.
Any way to do ?

Bands I need are 6,5,4,3 and 2. To vegetation classification I'll use 654 and the bands 432 are to layout map.

Comment: As far as I know, ArcGIS only does 4 band pansharpening.

Comment: more information needed. What are the 5 bands you want to pan sharpen?

Comment: Welcome! Please take the tour http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour and edit your question to let us know what you have tried so far/what has failed. There seem to be several Landsat 8 and ArcGIS questions on this site, have you taken a look at any of them?  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69575/landsat-in-arcgis  seems like it might be of use.

Comment: Bands 6,5,4,3 and 2. I need to classify the vegetation using 654 and the bands 432 are to layout map.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: the panchromatic band in Landsat covers B3 and B4. You will add spatial details when pansharpening but it is likely to distort your colours.

For visualisation, you can only display three bands at the time, so you could use some interactive function for display only. The workaround for pansharpening more than three or 4 bands using ESRI's algorithms is to do it several times.

In practice, you can add the image analysis window (from Windows menu), right click on your image (1),  click on function (2), change the function (3) and select Landsat 8 (4). It is hard to tell you which method works best because there is a part of subjectivity, but you don't need to worry if it is only for visualisation. This will create a temporary layer that you can make permanent if needed.

[image]

EDIT: as a remark, if you have the original product, you can look in catalog and expand the **_MTL.txt** file, which will give you a pansharpened image.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work in my situation because many people will use the data and it needs to be ready to be used.

Comment: as I mentioned, you can save the temporary layer as a permanent one if you want to distribute it. Note that the size will be multiplied by 4, though. The alternative is to distribute a lyr or mxd  and providing ont the fly pansharpen